# Can't find any div using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a weird problem with my code, I'm changing the background color of some divs using Javascript, but "document.getElementById" is not finding the div and returns NULL.

Javascript:

```
function colorFill(id)
{
   console.log(id); // Shows the correct string (r1h1)
   var divID = document.getElementById(id);
   // Even if I replace the id by "r1h1", directly the name of the div, it shows NULL
   console.log(divID); // Shows NULL
}
```

The "id" is a string coming from a php function, that works, because when I try do `alert(id)`, it shows up correctly (r1h1), but when I try to find the div using that "id", it returns a NULL. Also, I've tried to find other divs and it does the same.

Here's the div:

HTML:

```
<?php
    include 'models/ms_model.php';
    if (isset( $_SESSION['gameState'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['gameState'] ))
    { 
        fillGameTable();
    }
?>

<div id="row1" class="Row rowActive">
    <div id="r1h1" class="hole" style="float:left"></div>
</div>
```

I'm calling the Javascript function here:

PHP:

```
function fillGameTable()
{
    echo '<script src="views/js/ms.js"></script>';
    foreach($_SESSION['gameState'] as $ID)
    {
       echo'<script>colorFill("'.(string)$ID.'");</script>';
    }
}
```

The weirdest this is that I have another function finding that same div and it works, something is wrong with this function ...

Comment: what is the scope of id? Can you show the rest of the js?

Comment: [Appears to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/gq4vr83s/1/), `divID` should be an object, not a value while `id` will be the value passed to the function. You should [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead. Are you putting a string in your call to the function `colorFill()`?

Comment: Working here aswell. http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/14/ .If it doesn't find any element it's null. You should provide more code

Comment: You're including ms.js multiple times? Have you checked the console for errors? What is in ms.js?

Comment: ms.js is where the javascript function (colorFill) is.

Comment: Sorry for the code mess, isn't it supposed to find the div if I'm getting the string correctly?

Comment: This means that each time through the `foreach()` loop you're adding the `colorFill()` function, overwriting it each time. You need to load ms.js once and then call the function when you need it.

Comment: I've corrected that, but the same thing happens, I still get a null from the divID.

Comment: Are you sure all your id's are unique, cause that could cause some nasty js bugs if that isn't the case...

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that, it's unique, even if I replace the id by "r1h1", directly the name of the div, it shows NULL, something is wrong with the function, I can't find any div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the colorFill() function before the divs in the document. You either have to switch that order, to make sure that the elements are all in place in the document *before* you call the colorFill() JS function, like this:

```
<div id="row1" class="Row rowActive">
    <div id="r1h1" class="hole" style="float:left"></div>
</div>
<?php
    include 'models/ms_model.php';
    if (isset( $_SESSION['gameState'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['gameState'] )){ fillGameTable(); }
?>
```

Another option would be to refactor your code so that the fillGameTable() PHP function returns a javascript which is executed in the document ready event.

Comment: That obvious huh? Thanks a lot, I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the [JavaScript function](http://jsfiddle.net/gq4vr83s/2/) from PHP make sure you're quoting the argument for the function properly:

```
function colorFill(id)
{
   var divID = document.getElementById(id);
   console.log(divID);
}

colorFill(r1h1); // not a string, returns null
colorFill('r1h1'); // string, returns object
```

It is likely you have something like this in PHP:

```
echo "colorFill(" . $variable . ")";
```

What you need is this (note the inclusion of the quotes surrounding the argument):

```
    echo "colorFill('" . $variable . "')";
```

Comment: yeah, but the problem really seems to be finding the div, because the id is getting the string, console.log(id) shows me "r1h1", the only this that doesn't work is document.getElementById(id).

Comment: Because that would be correct @JoséPereira, the `id` is populated and shown. Whether it is a proper argument for your function *is a different issue*. Can you show us your PHP?

Comment: I added the PHP  where I call the Javascript function.